# How to get max available document height in a browser?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Can anyone tell me how can i get max available height when browser is maximised. Not screen, avilHeight or document.height.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("wrapper").style.height=screen.availHeight + "px";
</script>
```

For my resolution (1366x768) screen,avilHeight or document.height returns 728px which is the browser height but i want only max document height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an assumption based on `window.innerHeight`, `window.outerHeight`, and `screen.availHeight`:

```
var maximizedHeight = screen.availHeight - (window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight);
```

It’s not a particularly good solution, though. If your content adapts to any size, why not handle the `resize` event? If possible, CSS is even better – what’s the situation?

Comment: how can i do this in css ? when i set the height of div #wrapper to 100% it does nth it gets the height of content

Comment: @user2973528: It depends on your situation, but try `html, body { height: 100%; }`.

Comment: @user2973528: Could you link to a demonstration somewhere, please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/28MkL/4/ working fine here but in my website it gets the content of children

Answer (score 0):

```
function resolution()
{
        var width = window.innerWidth || html.clientWidth  || body.clientWidth  ||  screen.availWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight || html.clientHeight  || body.clientHeight  || screen.availHeight;
        res = {};   
        res.x = width;
        res.y = height;
        return res;
}
```